# How to check if one wildcard expression (AKA glob) contains another wildcard expression?

Tags: algorithm, pattern-matching, wildcard, glob, string-comparison

I have two wildcard expressions g1 and g2, and I would like to know whether g1 contains g2.
For example:

```
g1 = "*.txt"
g2 = "hello*.txt"
```

In this case g1 contains g2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, this involves a bunch of theory. But here is how I'd tackle it.

1. Convert [wildcards into DFAs](http://wpc.github.io/algorithm/2016/01/13/using-dfa-for-wildcard-matching-problem.html).
2. Calculate the intersection of the DFAs using the [product construction](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/6893/is-this-intersection-of-dfas-correct).
3. Look at the intersection to see if all of the accepting states of one DFA are in the other. If so, then it is contained in the other.

Bonus. You can use the same approach for comparing wildcards to regular expressions, as long as the regular expression really is regular. (eg No backreferences.)